# Axios erroring on encoding of response

Tags: node.js, rest, axios

I'm reading from Wikipedia fine until there are non-ascii chars. So searching for

> [https://en.wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/page/summary/Björk](https://en.wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/page/summary/Bj%C3%B6rk)

axios is responding with

```
type 'https://mediawiki.org/wiki/HyperSwitch/errors/bad_request',
method: 'get',
detail: 'title-invalid-characters',
uri: '/en.wikipedia.org/v1/page/summary/Bj%25F6rk'
```

I've tried setting **axios.defaults.headers.get** to:

```
{'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'}
```

and have also tried **encodeURI** (and **decodeURI** as I'm not sure which way the problem is!) but no joy.

EDIT: Here's my minimal code required to generate the error:

```
const axios = require('axios');

var titleurl = `https://en.wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/page/summary/Björk`;
axios.get(titleurl)
.then(function(resp) {
    if(resp && resp.data ) {
        console.log(resp.data);
    } else {
        console.log('not found');
    }
})
.catch(function(e) {
    console.error(e); // ends up here
});
```

Comment: How are you capturing this `Bj%25F6rk` value? Through user-input or is it coming from some database?

Comment: That's coming in the error object when axios fails

Comment: axios({
  method: "get",
  url: "https://en.wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/page/summary/Björk"
}).then((pingResp) => {
  console.log(pingResp);
  return pingResp;
}).catch(() => null);

This does not fail for me. I asked you that question specifically because I would like to know how you are passing Björk.

Comment: It's definitely failing at that point for me, so it must be the config of my axios perhaps? In the error object I'm seeing the correct bjork (WITH the umlaut) in the 'current url' field, but the encoded bj%25F6rk in the resp.data object...

Comment: I've added the simplified code, be interested to know what you get?

Comment: Yup, what is happening now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189612/discussion-between-user4893295-and-avanthika).